# Select data attribute within object tags for an SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a relatively large SVG file, so much so that I would not like to put the entire XML code into my html file. As such, I have been using the object tags to refer to it and implement effects such as changing the transparency within css.

However, I would now like to use some javascript to select this object element and when clicked, change the data attribute to load a different SVG file (essentially alternating between images).

This is a trivial operation using normal img tags but the same approach doesn't seem to work using the object tags.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<div class="title-bar">
        <h1 class="heading">A Gathering of ...</h1>
        <object id="trooper" data="images/trooper.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</div>
```

For the html, and for the javascript:

```
addEventListener("load", start);
// else { attachEvent("onload", start); }

function start(){
    var logo = document.querySelector("#trooper");
    logo.addEventListener("click", logoChange);
}

function logoChange(){
    console.log("Clicked");
    var src = this.getAttribute("data");

    if(src === "images/trooper.svg"){
        this.setAttribute("data", "images/rebel.svg");
    } else {
        this.setAttribute("data", "images/trooper.svg");
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It should work. Have you tried other UAs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would just use the img Tag and avoid the object (don't know the current status, but when I messed around it with Flash some years ago ... strange things happened quite too often):

```
<img src="images/trooper.svg"></img>
```

An then just change the source like you used to do ...

(but you can't have JS inside you SVG with img)

Comment: problem with this is that the parameter features of SVG do not work with img and requires the object tag.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are using this inside of the logoChange function.
you will have to use the logo variable for getting and setting values.

Comment: I did have that initially, but it too did not work. I think the problem seems to be with actually selecting the logo. I also used getElementById at first, to no avail.

Comment: sorry, take a look at what hutzlibu had to say